# Sass-loader and node-sass (and therefore nuxt-sass-resources-loader aswel) required as prod dependencies

Tags: nuxt.js

I have the following demo app to show my configuration: https://github.com/jovanmaric/nuxt-demo

When I deploy the app to Heroku, I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot resolve "node-sass" from "/app"`

The same error repeats with nuxt-sass-resources-loader and sass-loader. However from my understanding
the scss > css compilation happens at build time (npm run build) and not on runtime, mitigating the need
for 'node-sass', 'sass-loader' and 'nuxt-sass-resources-loader' to be installed as production dependencies.

The above error shows even without 'nuxt-sass-resources-loader'. Is it intended to have these libraries as production dependencies and not as 
devDependencies? Considering that `https://nuxtjs.org/faq/pre-processors/` lists the `--save-dev` flag?